# Magically Undo fprintf format Mistake

Tags: c

I have some code that was logging data from a device and was timestamping that data with system time in milliseconds.

I was using a `uint64_t` to store the timestamp, which was created like this:

```
struct timespec request;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &request);
uint64_t stamp0 = (uint64_t)((uint64_t)request.tv_sec * 1000 + (uint64_t)request.tv_nsec / 1000000);
```

Then I wrote the timestamp to file (without thinking it through) like this:

```
fprintf(ptr,"%ld\n",(long)stamp0);
```

Now I have incorrect timestamps in my files that look like `1130802699` but should look like `1478599582064`.

Is there anything I can do to fix my error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that the timestamp `1130802699` should be more like `1478599552523` than `1478599582064`.

If so, you may be able to recover the timestamps by adding the appropriate multiple of 1<<32 (I'm assuming that your `long` is 32 bits and the truncated values don't roll over into negative range).  In this case, that's 344 times, or `1477468749824` to add to each value.

Your 32-bit values will roll over every 6 weeks or so, so you might have to do something a bit cleverer if your files span a longer range.

---

If you're wondering how I came up with that value, we should work backwards.

We know we truncated the `uint64_t` to (roughly) `int32_t`, and if we make some reasonable assumptions (e.g. 2's complement arithmetic), that means masking with 0xffffffff:

```
stamp0 & 0xffffffff
```

That's equivalent to subtracting

```
stamp0 - (stamp0 & 0xffffffff00000000)
```

This difference will be constant across a large range of values, and approximately equal to the difference between the actual and expected values.

1478599582064 - 1130802699 is 1477468779365, or 0x15800007365.

So I think the offset to add back on is actually 0x15800000000.

Comment: Thanks, the timestamps weren't exact matches so I suspect you're right. Luckily it was only over the course of an hour or so, so roll-over shouldn't be a problem. Could you explain to me how you arrived at the value `344` please?

Comment: Thanks, that really helps, you've saved me a lot of pain.